# Time format in R is showing only one value for all rows after attempting to fix it

Tags: r, time-format

Trying to figure out why my time formating for this dataset in R is not producing the correct outcome.

I'm attempting to fix the format in the timestamp data

This is the code I have:

```
intensities_h$ActivityHour=as.POSIXct(intensities_h$ActivityHour, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz=Sys.timezone())
intensities_h$date <- format(intensities_h$ActivityHour, format = "%m/%d/%y")
intensities_h$time <- format(intensities_h$ActivityHour, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

The output is showing 00:00:00 in the time column for all rows!

[Screenshot of the table view after formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSo6v.png) 
[Screenshot before formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf40Z.png)

Any thoughts?

Comment: In your first line you are stripping time off of ActivityHour. Remove the format, or use a format that includes time information?

Comment: you create the timestamp using no time-elements, i.e. `format="%m/%d/%Y"`. So where should the hours come from?

Comment: Sorry so I modified the question. I did end up adding time format to the first line but I'm still getting 00:00:00 for all rows of ActivityHour:
intensities_h$ActivityHour=as.POSIXct(intensities_h$ActivityHour, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz=Sys.timezone())

Comment: Looks like `ActivityHour` does not contain any time data....

Comment: @Wimpel it did. The screenshot is for the data after it was formatted with the code

Comment: add some relevant sample data please...

Comment: @Wimpel just added another screenshot

Comment: `as.POSIXct("4/12/2016 1:00:00 AM", format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")` works fine for me. returns `#[1] "2016-04-12 01:00:00 CEST"`... so the problem lies somewhere else.. Since you have only provided images of data , and not real sample data, your errors/results are not reproducible..

Comment: @Wimpel Very new to all of this even kaggle. I managed to copy all the code there and include the datasets: [Kaggle Case Study](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ghassans/bellabeat-case-study/)

Comment: Just post some sample data, like `dput(head(intensities_h))`